# Controller Class Not Found - Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

My Controller for my class 'Article' cannot be found.

I am needing to fetch all entries from the article table.

I am able to use the DB:: facade to pull what's in the DB, but when I try using Article::all() I get:

```
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Article' not found

in ArticleController.php line 15
at Application->Laravel\Lumen\{closure}()
```

Line 15 looks like:

```
$article = Article::all();
```

This is what I've tried so far, but with no success:

- updated .env.example to .env and set up my DB credentials.
- in bootstrap/app.php I've uncommented `Dotenv::load(__DIR__.'/../');`
- In bootstrap/app.php I've uncommented `$app->withFacades(); $app->withEloquent();`
- I've tried to use the full route of the controller in routes.php: `$app->get('article', 'App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController@index');`

My model directory is located under app->Models and has my Article.php model:

```
<?php

# app/Models/Article.php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Article extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'articles';
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'content'];
}
```

My Controller is ArticleController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;


class ArticleController extends Controller{

    public function index(){

        $article = Article::all();

        return response()->json($article);
    }
}
```

And my routes.php

```
<?php

$app->get('article', 'ArticleController@index');
```

I really appreciate any help on this error. I've unfortunately spent the better part of 2 days on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the proper namespace. Your `Article` model is in the `App\Models` namespace so you need to add this to the top of your controller:

```
use App\Models\Article;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run `composer update`. a new autoload classmap will be generated and all your new composer will be ready to autoload after successful update.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses and for your answer @Thomas. I followed your response and was able to add the correct namespace in my controller.